# Apache2 error 200 OK

Tags: php, error-handling, http-headers, apache2

i have some annoying error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>200 OK</title>
</head><body>
<h1>OK</h1>
<p>The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.</p>
</body></html>
```

The PHP code:

```
.
.
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($rows); $i++) {
    $Lenght = mt_rand(300, 400);
                    for ($x = 0; $x < $Lenght; $x++) {
                        $NColumn1 .= mt_rand(0, 9);
                        $NColumn2 .= mt_rand(0, 9);
                    }
                    $database->exec("UPDATE Child SET Column1 = '$NColumn1', Column2 = '$NColumn2' WHERE Parent_ID = '$Parent_ID';");
                }
```

I have 300 records in a table Child where I UPDATE with new one and that works just fine but during this proces I  get a downloaded php file with 200 OK and in background my table is updating. I am using ***Zend Server CE SP1 5.6.0 with PHP 5.4 and Apache2***. I searched and fond somthing about **HEADER** handlings and in php.ini file to change **allow_url_fopen = On** to **allow_url_fopen = Off , and search error log in Apache2**. So I try all of that but nothing. 
So, is it possible to fix or disable that kind of error or do somthing to avoid it? Realy need a good help!

Comment: What configuration for php are you using? Module, cgi, fcgi?

Comment: It is configured to SERVER API: CGI/FCGI

Comment: You should have error messages in a php error log in this case. I suspect that the php daemon is not returning any response which results in the error that you are getting.

Comment: In C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\logs i found only php.log. After I run a script there is no error.

Answer (score 2):

I've just hit the same problem and found this link:
[ZendEnablerConf.xml](http://www.muenster-webdesign.net/blog/zend-server-community-edition/)

You may want to translate it from German. ;)

I believe that you need to look for ZendEnablerConf.xml and change the timeouts:

```
<timeout connectionTimeout = "60" requestTimeout = "300" />
```

Comment: The site you're linking to has a bad WebOfTrust rating (also, it's german). Is there a better resource you could link to?